# Merge associative array using a mapping array with an array with partial keys ( support for named parameters )

Tags: php, arrays

Without going into great detail, this is for a template system I am developing, specifically to support named parameters in my template filters and functions.

I will try to get to the point and explain the problem as best I can, using my escapeHtml filter which is basically `htmlspecialchars` in native PHP.

Consider, I have this mapping array ( this will change based on the function or filter being evoked )

```
$mapping = array(
    'string' => array(
        'type' => 'string'
    ),
    'flags' => array(
        'type' => 'integer',
        'default' => 11
    ),
    'encoding' => array(
        'type' => 'string',
        'default' => 'UTF-8'
    ),
    'double_encode' => array(
        'type' => 'boolean',
        'default' => true
    )
);
```

To explain this, the first level key such as `flags` is the input name, the `type` is the supported input type ( this is not important to this question ). the `default` is simply the default value to use if none is supplied in the input.  Now the code that I am developing allows some input that I must map out to this array, the input may be indexed ( numerically ) or with a key that matches the input name above.  The mapping array is in the correct or expected order for the indexed inputs.

So some examples of input,

```
$input = array(
    'string' => 'hello',
     0 => 'ISO-8859-1',
    1 => false,
    'flags' => 3
 );
```

Now I need to reconcile this with the mapping array, such that the output is this,

```
$output = array(
    'string' => 'hello',
    'flags' => 3
    'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1',
    'double_encode' => false,
);
```

So if you follow so far, I need the items with keys to match the mapping array, and any remaining elements ( numeric index ) to be added in the order they appear in.  There is some error checking involved but I am not overly worried about this at the moment.

I do have this working, but it took me about 70 lines of code and 3 loops so if you can beat that as an added bonus you get credit for it in the projects source code :). I have yet to add any code( it's to unstable at the moment ) but the Git Repo is here:

https://github.com/ArtisiticPhoenix/Jet/

That said, I have added a lot of stuff to the readme and wiki.  This bit below here is not important to the question but should offer some content.  In my template system, filters are invoked in template source this way.

```
{ $variable|escapeHtml } //no params
{ $variable|escapeHtml( ) } //no params
{ $variable|escapeHtml( 3, 'ISO-8859-1', false) } //indexed params
{ $variable|escapeHtml( flags=3, double_encode=true, encoding='ISO-8859-1') } //intended support for named params
{ $variable|escapeHtml( 'ISO-8859-1', false, flags = 3) } //support for mixed params as in the example
```

In the case of filters such as above the first input is the value of the variable `$variable` now this will ultimately be compiled into a PHP class by my template system that looks something like this.

```
    $output .= $this->isPrintable(
        $this->_executeCallable( [
            400,/* Token::T_FILTER */
            'escapehtml',/* TagType */
            ['string'=>$this->get('variable'), 'flags'=>3, 'encoding'=>'ISO-8859-1', 'double_encode'=>true ]
        ] ),
        'for variable[ T_VARIABLE_TAG::$variable ] on Line[ 2 ] In Template[ test.tpl ]'
    );
```

Needless to say I hopefully can get a answer with less then 3 loops and 70+ lines of code.

Thanks,

EDIT:: this is approximately what I have now, a small amount of this was to save some time when the input is simpler then the mixed type or basically it matches the map numeric indexed.  Also I have some error checking in here for missing required parameters, ie. those not in the input that do not have a default value in the mapping array.

```
    echo '<pre>';

    $map = array(
            'string' => array(
                    'type' => 'string'
            ),
            'flags' => array(
                    'type' => 'integer',
                    'default' => 11
            ),
            'encoding' => array(
                    'type' => 'string',
                    'default' => 'UTF-8'
            ),
            'double_encode' => array(
                    'type' => 'boolean',
                    'default' => true
            )
    );

    $input = array(
            'string' => 'hello',
            0 => 'ISO-8859-1',
            1 => false,
            'flags' => 3
    );

    /* //simple indexed input
    $input = array(
        'hello',
        3,
        'ISO-8859-1',
        false
    );
    */

    $isNumeric = true;
    foreach ( $input as $k => $v){
        if(!is_numeric($k)){
            $isNumeric = false;
        }
    }

    if( !$isNumeric || count( $map ) != count( $input )){
        $numeric = array();
        $assoc = array();
        //split input into associative and indexed keys
        foreach ( $input as $k => $v){
            if(!is_numeric($k)){
                $assoc[$k] = $v;
            }else{
                $numeric[] = $v;
            }
        }

        //setup a dummy array based off the map keys
        $output = array_fill_keys( array_keys( $map ), '_UNSET_');

        foreach( $output as $key => &$value ){
            if( isset( $assoc[ $key ] ) ){
                $value = $assoc[ $key ];
                unset( $assoc[$key] );
            }else if( count( $numeric ) > 0 ){
                $value = array_shift( $numeric );
            }else{
                if( isset( $map[ $key ][ 'default' ]) ){
                    $value = $map[ $key ][ 'default' ];
                }else{
                    //throw error for missing required param
                    die( "missing required param $key on ".__LINE__);
                }
            }
        }

        if( count( $assoc ) > 0 ){
            var_export( $assoc );
            die( "unused inputs on ".__LINE__);
        }

        if( count( $numeric ) > 0 ){
            var_export( $numeric );
            die( "unused inputs on ".__LINE__);
        }
    }else{
        $output = array_combine(array_keys( $map ), $input);
    }


    var_export( $output );
```

It just feels like there is a better way to do it then that mess.

Update 2: I should have mentioned input may not contain the full set of items above, as in my template example it may just be the first parameter.  In which case I have to use the default values.

Update 3: got it thanks to @darp for his help, with a slight modification here is my final code for it.

```
    echo '<pre>';

    $mapping = array( 
        'string' => array(
                'type' => 'string'
        ),
        'flags' => array(
                'type' => 'integer',
                'default' => 11
        ),
        'encoding' => array(
                'type' => 'string',
                'default' => 'UTF-8'
        ),
        'double_encode' => array(
                'type' => 'boolean',
                'default' => true
        )
    );

    /*$input = array(
            0 => 'test', //string
            'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1',
            'double_encode' => false,
            1 => 3, //flags
    );*/

    /* //error: missing required param[ string ]
        $input = array(
            'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1',
            'double_encode' => false,
            'flags' => 3,
    );*/

    /*
    $input = array(  //missing optional flags
            0 => 'test', //string
            'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1',
            'double_encode' => false,
    );
    */


    $namedParams    = array_intersect_key($input, $mapping);
    $numberedParams = array_diff_key($input, $mapping);
    $unmappedKeys   = array_keys(array_diff_key($mapping, $input));

    $mappedParams = array();
    foreach ( $unmappedKeys as $index => $unmapped ){
        if( isset( $numberedParams[ $index ] ) ){
            $mappedParams[ $unmapped ] = $numberedParams[ $index ];
        }else{
            if( !isset( $mapping[ $unmapped ]['default'] ) ){
                die( "error:missing required param[ {$unmapped} ]on ".__LINE__);
            }else{
                $mappedParams[ $unmapped ] = $mapping[ $unmapped ]['default'];
            }
        }
    }

    $output = array_merge($namedParams, $mappedParams);

    var_export($output);
```

Outputs in the first case:

```
array (
  'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1',
  'double_encode' => false,
  'string' => 'test',
  'flags' => 3,
)
```

In the second I get an error as I should because I am missing a required value:

And in the third:

```
array (
  'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1',
  'double_encode' => false,
  'string' => 'test',
  'flags' => 11,
)
```

If there are extra they are just ignored at the moment, I should check for them but it's not that big of a deal.  I am just trying to avoid that magic black box that a lot of frameworks have.  The only other thing I could add is sorting them into the right order, but I am not sure if I need to yet, it depends how I implement invoking the functions etc..

Anyway Thanks,

Comment: I feel like you should share those 3 loops and 70+ lines of code...

Comment: I will give me a few minutes to work out some of the dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes care of the mapping, handles missing parameter, applying defaults where they're missing or their values are null:

```
// Get the named parameters from the input array.
$namedParams = array_intersect_key($input, $mapping);

// Get the mapping keys for those missing from input.
$unmappedKeys = array_keys(array_diff_key($mapping, $input));

// Get the unnamed parameters from the input.
// Pad the array with null placeholders for those missing.
$numberedParams = array_pad(
    array_diff_key($input, $mapping),
    count($unmappedKeys),
    null);

// Map keys to the unnamed parameters.
$mappedParams = array_combine($unmappedKeys, $numberedParams);

// Merge.
$output = array_merge($namedParams, $mappedParams);

// Apply defaults from the $mapping array to parameters with null values.
array_walk(
    $output,
    function (&$v, $k, $m) {
        $v = is_null($v) ? $m[$k]['default'] : $v;
    },
    $mapping
);
```

---

`var_export($output)`:

```
array (
    'string' => 'hello',
    'flags' => 3,
    'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1',
    'double_encode' => false,
)
```

Comment: Actually I have to do error checking before array_combine, I like this answer because I thought of doing it in a similar way, just couldn't wrap my head around it.

Comment: actually it's good, I already made the changes I needed, to check for missing params that have a default value is the big one.  With that it's not much smaller then my original one.  I might have to do some bench marking to see which is faster, although It might help me cut out a few of the parts of the original one.

Comment: Thanks, the only real issue is that array_combine will throw a warning if the two arrays are not the same length, so I can use everything up to there.  I also don't really have to include the defaults, I just need to make sure the ones without defaults are not missing.  I can modify the mapping, I'm using reflection to generate it by default.

Comment: @derp, sorry i missed that part, but it can go the other way too with extra ones, I think I can just combine all that into a simple loop instead of the array_combine & array_merge & array_walk part, no doubt that is the tricky part, the first part before that is good though.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested it but this should be close to what you want I think.

```
array_merge(
  array_replace(
    array_intersect_key($mapping, $input),
    array_intersect_key($input, $mapping)
  ),
  array_combine(
      array_keys(array_diff_key($mapping, $input)), 
      array_values(array_diff_key($input, $mapping))
  )
)
```

Comment: This works, but it is too condensed for my use case, I have some variations and error checking I have to do, and there is no way to hook them in.

Comment: DAPOR - declare, assign, process, output, return.  declare and assign your array, then use array_walk or another array tranversal to validate the data after assignment.